# Reporting meta analysis

Tags: graduate-school

I’m a grad student working on an assignment that involves stating the effectiveness of an intervention for students with learning disabilities. I used a meta analysis to support the effectiveness and am not sure how to report everything in one page and which sections to include. Specifically, I don’t know where to report how the effect was calculated (under which section). I don’t have much  knowledge in this area so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why one page? This isn't really the place for help on assignments.

Answer (score 0):

While the standards of how to report something in a publication vary widely by field and venue, the variation of what is expected in a class assignment is vastly larger - too large for really anyone outside of your class to say.

If this were for publication, I would suggest you find papers in your field and from the publication source you are targeting to help guide you in how to structure reporting your findings. For an assignment, the only standard that will have much of any sway is what your instructor expects or requires - so I would highly recommend you review the assignment guidelines and syllabus, and then contact the instructor to request guidance on how to structure and summarize your findings, including what details they want included.